# java service wrapper

Tags: java, swing, service, wrapper

I have a Swing Java application; assume it is just like calculator. What I want to do is

1. Start this automatically in start up
2. Run as a Windows service
3. Show an icon in the system tray when it closes.

Using Java service wrapper, I have made it to Windows service; but it is still not starting on reboot, nor does an icon display in the tray.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson , can't you understand the problem i have ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [winrun4j](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) or [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)

For java service wrapper tutorial, have a look to [this article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32068)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html
I believe that this is exactly what you need.

Comment: read the link I sent. I cannot explain better than it is already explained.

Comment: why can't u understand? I want to run in windows, not in linux

Comment: @shan this text is from the link: "It can run on Win32 via the Cygwin emulation layer (see Cygwin for more information), however Win32 users may prefer to use procrun instead, which allows the application to run as a Windows Service."